# How to query a balance metric from a table that is not snapshotted

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, query-optimization, snapshot

**Problem:**
Query optimization - current solution takes 10+ mins to complete, which is too long for reporting purposes.

**Goal:**
Report out active customers by day. An active customer is someone who has made a purchase in the last year.

**Sample Dataset**:
Customer_Id | Order_Date 
1 | 1/1/2014 
1 | 1/2/2014 
2 | 1/1/2014 
3 | 1/1/2014 
3 | 1/3/2014

**Result set needed:**
Snapshot_Date | Active_Customers 
1/1/2014 | 3 
1/2/2014 | 3 
1/3/2014 | 3 
...
1/1/2015 | 3 
1/2/2015 | 2 
1/3/2015 | 1

**Current Query:**

```
--Date Dimension table
CREATE TABLE #Snapshot ( Snapshot DATE )
INSERT  INTO #Snapshot
        ( Snapshot )
VALUES  ( '1/1/2014' ) ,
        ( '1/2/2014' ) ,
        ( '1/3/2014' ) ,
             ...
        ( '1/1/2015' ) ,
        ( '1/2/2015' ) ,
        ( '1/3/2015' ) 

--Orders Table
CREATE TABLE #Orders ( Customer_Id INT , Order_Date DATE )
INSERT INTO #Orders ( Customer_Id , Order_Date )
VALUES ( 1, '1/1/2014' ),
       ( 1, '1/2/2014' ),
       ( 2, '1/1/2014' ),
       ( 3, '1/1/2014' ),
       ( 3, '1/3/2014' )

--Query
SELECT  a.Snapshot ,
        SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, a.Last_Order, a.Snapshot) <= 365 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Active_Customers
FROM    ( SELECT    a.Snapshot ,
                    b.Customer_Id ,
                    MAX(b.Order_Date) AS Last_Order
          FROM      #Snapshot a
                    JOIN #Orders b ON b.Order_Date <= a.Snapshot
          GROUP BY  a.Snapshot ,
                    b.Customer_Id
        ) a
GROUP BY a.Snapshot
```

**Issues:**
The query gets bogged down due to the join within the sub-select.  If the orders table has 1 million rows, and the date dimension table has 1,000 rows, the join creates ~ 1 billion rows.

*Is there a way to create the same result set while eliminating the inner join within the sub-select to prevent the many-to-many relationship?*

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend a different approach, one that uses cumulative sums rather than a separate count for each day -- this is much faster.

The idea is to add a new customer every time a new customer appears or an order has not been seen for one year.  Similarly, subtract a customer 365 days later -- unless a new order has appear.  The rest is then cumulative sums.  All of this is supported in SQL Server 2012.

The following will give the report for each day where there is an order:

```
WITH o as (
      SELECT o.*, 
             LAG(Order_Date) OVER (PARTITION BY Customer_Id ORDER BY Order_Date) as prev_OrderDate,
             LEAD(Order_Date) OVER (PARTITION BY Customer_Id ORDER BY Order_Date) as next_OrderDate
      FROM Orders o 
     )
SELECT thedate, SUM(inc), SUM(SUM(inc)) OVER (ORDER BY thedate)
FROM ((SELECT o.OrderDate as thedate, 1 as inc
       FROM o
       WHERE prev_OrderDate IS NULL OR DATEADD(year, 1, prev_OrderDate) < Order_Date
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT o.OrderDate + 365, -1 as inc
       FROM o
       WHERE next_OrderDate IS NULL OR DATEADD(year, -1, next_OrderDate > Order_Date
      )
     ) d
GROUP BY thedate
```